# Talking about medicine: How to say “I’m on x” in German

Tags: translation, english-to-german, phrase-request

When going to the doctor or pharmacy, how do you say “I’m currently on/taking *x*” [insert name of medicine]. Google Translate is giving me the literal translation of *nehmen* which I’m pretty sure it isn’t right.

Comment: But it is.......

Comment: Don't be tempted to use a literal translation - "Ich bin auf xxx" works well with drugs, but not with medicine and will convey the meaning of "I am addicted to xxx" / "intoxicated with xxx"

Comment: Although I often here it used for comedic effect. ‘Nee, ich trink heut nix, ich bin auf Paracetamol.’

Answer (score 3):

For example, you are taking Aspirin.

You can simply say;

> Ich nehme derzeit Aspirin (ein).

Before a meal

> Ich nehme derzeit Aspirin vor dem Essen (ein)

During a meal

> Ich nehme derzeit Aspirin zum Essen (ein)

After a meal

> Ich nehme derzeit Aspirin nach dem Essen (ein)

In this link, you can find lots of terms related to this topic: [for more](http://www.senioren-ratgeber.de/Medikamente)

Comment: The tongue-in-cheek "Ich bin auf Aspirin", making it sound like you're a drug addict, is not too uncommon, either.

Comment: No, the *ein* is not optional. With *ein* it sounds like ‘I’m taking a pill of aspirin right at this moment.’ Without *ein* it’s ‘I have taken aspirin today’ or ’I regularly take aspirin.’

Comment: @ Jan While not applicable to the Aspirin of the answer,  the regular process is just what the original question asks for.

Comment: @Jan I have editted the answer:)

Answer (score 2):

After some consideration, I'd like to supply some more choices.

The most universal is, also appropriate to non-medicines like alcohol

> Ich stehe unter xxx (-Einfluss).

I also vote for

> Ich nehme (außerdem/ n-mal täglich) xxx (ein?).

As Jan points out, this strongly suggests regularity, but I guess, this applies to *I'm on xxx* the same way.

Most striking example:

> Ich nehme die Pille.

Note, that *ein* implies, the medicine is applied orally. It does not intuitively suggest other appliance methods e.g. ointments, injections...

In the latter case this sentence may work

> Ich spritze xxx ( z. B. Insulin)

Other possibilities include:

> Ich werde mit xxx behandelt

(Indicates, a doctor is involved)

or even:

> Ich bin in einer xxx-Therapie.